# Перезапись указателя на элемент структуры

Tags: c, массивы, оператор-присваивания

Есть структура ex, в ней есть данные. Нужно скопировать поле в структуру ex2.
Поле - строка. Возможно ли не копировать строку используя `strcpy();` , а перезаписать указатель ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct q{
    char pole[200];
}test1;

typedef struct q2{
   char pole[200];
}test2;

int main(void)
{
  test1 ex[1];
  test2 ex2[1];

  strcpy((*ex).pole, "qwer"); // заносим данные для примера

  ex2.pole = &ex.pole; // перезапись указателя (?)

  printf("%s",(*ex2).pole);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "...а перезаписать указатель". Какой указатель? У вас в коде не объявлено ни одного указателя.

Comment: а разве имя массива не является указателем на его 0 элемент ?

Comment: Нет. Имя массива в ряде оговоренных контекстов *неявно приводится* к типу указатель с образованием временного значения типа указатель. Но массив ни в коем случае не *является*  указателем. Никакого указателя там нет и перезаписывать там нечего.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из того, что вы пытаетесь сделать, можно предположить, что вы являетесь жертвой популярной мисконцепции о том, что массив в С якобы является указателем и этот указатель якобы можно как-то "перезаписать".

Массив в С не является указателем. Поэтому возможности перезаписать некий "указатель" в данном случае нет.

Answer (score 2):

Вот если бы структуры были объявлены как

```
typedef struct q{
    char *pole;
}test1;
```

Тогда да, хотя - ценой определенных сложностей (с выделением памяти, освобождением и т.п.)

Answer (score 1):

В обоих структурах у вас объявлены символьные массивы. Массивы не имеют операции присваивания. Вы не можете присвоить имени массива указатель. Вы лишь можете копировать элементы одного массива в другой.